# Updating App with new version on app store and when to change app details?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have made new version of the app and i want to update it on apple store. Also i want to change some keywords and screen shots, because there are new features.

But browsing the stack overflow i noticed that some of these properties are editable only during the upload. Since i don't want to mess things up, and it is delicate matter, i would like step by step instructions, if possible.

So do I first upload binary (in xode archive and then distribute), and after that go to my developer account and edit things, or reverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two items that are locked after app submission are Screenshots and Keywords. Description Metadata may be updated at any time, even after approval. Data in the "Version Information" section cannot be edited after the app is made "Ready for Sale" with the exception of the copyright notice.

The process you will most likely want to follow is:

1. Create a "New Version" placeholder for your app in iTunesConnect
2. Update your Keywords
3. Update your Screenshots (Be sure to include 3.5", 4", and iPad if applicable)
4. Update Description
5. Set App as "Ready to Upload Binary"
6. Submit the binary -- AFTER THIS POINT YOU WILL BE UNABLE TO EDIT SCREENSHOTS OR KEYWORDS WITHOUT REJECTING THE BINARY
7. After Approval, you can still edit Description

Hope this helps!

Comment: One question where to set"Ready to Upload Binary", i have just status  Prepare for Upload, that can't be edited, is that the same?

Comment: The "Ready to Upload Binary" is what the button in the upper right hand corner of the App Detail page will say. Once you click that button, you can submit your app through Xcode or Application Loader. Take a look at [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TAggG.png)  to get an idea of what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this for my first app :P

1. click the app you want to update in "Manage your apps".
2. then add version.
3. edit everything you want! and done.